# How to efficiently store bitmaps in Android?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, jpeg, store

I'm building a relatively basic news-reader app that involves displaying news in a custom listview (Image + Title + Short Description per list element).

My question is How can I store the images I download from the server and then attach them to the listview? The images will be relatively small, 200 X 200 usually, in .jpeg format.

It's not so much a question of how as much as "how to do it efficiently", as I'm already noticing lag in lower-end phones when using the default "ic_launcher" icon instead of bitmaps.

Would it be faster to store them as files or into the news database along with other news data when the app starts and syncs up the news or cache them...?

How should I go about this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lag"? Stuttering in your ListView or long loading times till the picture is displayed?

Comment: There are a few techniques you can use to improve preformance. See [this page in the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: Stuttering in the listview when using the ic_launcher image instead of the actual bitmaps. The question is how do I store the bitmaps efficiently before applying them?

Comment: @Eugen you're welcome, hope it helps. Note I found it to be much easier to download the BitmapFun.zip project that is on the top right of that page and re-use the classes insdie the com.example.android.bitmapfun.util package rather than implementing all of the techniques for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better you can do it's use SoftReference via an ImageManager class.

In you ListAdpater getView() method call the displayImage() method of ImageManager.

ImageManager Coding Exemple :

```
public class ImageManagerExemple {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ImageManager";

private static ImageManagerExemple instance = null;

public static ImageManagerExemple getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ImageManagerExemple(context);
    } 
    return instance;        
}   

private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> imageMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

private Context context;
private File cacheDir;

private ImageManagerExemple(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();      
        cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/yourappname");
    } else {
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    }
    if(!cacheDir.exists()) {
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
}


/**
 * Display web Image loading thread
 * @param imageUrl picture web url
 * @param imageView target
 * @param imageWaitRef picture during loading
 */
public void displayImage(String imageUrl, ImageView imageView, Integer imageWaitRef) {
    String imageKey = imageUrl;     
    imageView.setTag(imageKey);
    if(imageMap.containsKey(imageKey) && imageMap.get(imageKey).get() != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = imageMap.get(imageKey).get();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else {
        queueImage(imageUrl, imageView);
        if(imageWaitRef != null)
            imageView.setImageResource(imageWaitRef);
    }
}

private void queueImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    ImageRef imgRef=new ImageRef(url, imageView);
    // Start thread
    Thread imageLoaderThread = new Thread(new ImageQueueManager(imgRef));
    // Make background thread low priority, to avoid affecting UI performance
    imageLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);
    imageLoaderThread.start();
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    try {
        // Is the bitmap in our cache?
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
        if(bitmap != null) return bitmap;
        // Nope, have to download it
        bitmap = ImageServerUtils.pictureUrlToBitmap(url);
        // save bitmap to cache for later
        writeFile(bitmap, f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ""+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }  catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "OutOfMemoryError : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
    if (bmp != null && f != null) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally { 
            try { if (out != null ) out.close(); }
            catch(Exception ex) {} 
        }
    }
}


private class ImageRef {
    public String imageUrl;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageRef(String imageUrl, ImageView i) {
        this.imageUrl=imageUrl;
        this.imageView=i;
    }
}

private class ImageQueueManager implements Runnable {
    private ImageRef imageRef;
    public ImageQueueManager(ImageRef imageRef) {
        super();
        this.imageRef = imageRef;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageRef imageToLoad = this.imageRef;
        if (imageToLoad != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(imageToLoad.imageUrl);
            String imageKey = imageToLoad.imageUrl;
            imageMap.put(imageKey, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bmp));
            Object tag = imageToLoad.imageView.getTag();

            // Make sure we have the right view - thread safety defender
            if (tag != null && ((String)tag).equals(imageKey)) {
                BitmapDisplayer bmpDisplayer = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, imageToLoad.imageView);                         
                Activity a = (Activity)imageToLoad.imageView.getContext();                          
                a.runOnUiThread(bmpDisplayer);
            } 
        } 
    }
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
private class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
        bitmap=b;
        imageView=i;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to getting smooth ListView scrolling without stutter is to not update it in any way, shape or form while the user is scrolling it. Afaik, this is essentially how iOS manages to get its ListViews that smooth: it disallows any changes to it (and the UI in general) while the user has his finger on it.

Just comment out any code that changes your ListView while leaving all the bitmap loading code intact, and you'll see that the actual loading of the bitmaps in the background doesn't really impact performance at all. The problem is that the UI thread can't keep up with view updates and scrolling at the same time.

You can achieve the same thing by using a `OnScrollListener` that blocks all updates to the ListView while the User is scrolling it. As soon as the user stops, you can sneak in all pending updates.
For added performance, try not to use `notifyDataSetChanged` but iterate over the views of the ListView and only update the views that have actually changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really interesting what you're saying, things I didn't know. The problem is I'm not using notifyDataSetChanged() nor other list-modifiers. The images are loaded prior to launching the listview activity, not in the background.

Comment: What I'd also like to know is how to cut loading time by storing the images. I imagine caching them is the fastest way...?

Comment: I solved this problem in my imaging app by making my own cache of the images in native code memory space. My thumbnails are smaller and I allow 8K of RAM per image, so storing 2000 images is not that big a deal.

Comment: When retrieving images from the network you should usually use a 2 level cache (filesystem + memory), yes. I'm not entirely sure whether that's your problem, though, since you said it still lags even after using ic_launcer as an icon..? Loading local drawables is usually so fast that you should hardly notice it.

Comment: @BitBank Is that before or after you decode the images? Just so that everyone reading this is aware, bitmaps are stored uncompressed with 24 bits per pixel (depending on the BitmapConfig) in memory. That's much, much bigger than the actual files (8K for example would amount to a 18x18 thumbnail).

Comment: I decode the images with my own native code library. If there's an embedded thumbnail that's small, I use it. If not, I decode the images at a reduced resolution and re-encode as JPEG at a quality level which fits in under 8K.